# How to extract elements from a list of dimension (N, 2)

Tags: python, list

I have a list as below

```
list = [(1, 'a'),
 (2, 'b'),
 (3, 'c'),
 (4, 'd'),
 (5, 'e')]
```

I want to get a list

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I do like this

```
newlist = []
for i in range(5):
    newlist.append(list [i][1])
```

It's a correct way but I guess there is simpler way, isn't it?

Comment: use a list comprehension: `newlist = [i[1] for i in mylist]`. Also, you should avoid using `list` as a variable name to not override the builtin type `list`

Comment: @sacul I've already understood this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list compression:

```
new_list = [element[1] for element in list]
```